# How can I get length of a form element from another HTML document?

Tags: javascript

I have to html pages: Submit owner info page and the second page called submit car info
second page contains a form with ID=car_info.

I want to get the length of the form in the second page when I click on the next button which is available in the first html page (Owner info).
I noticed that document.getelementbyid(id).length works only on the fist page.

Any help

Comment: connect your script tag to another HTML page, call that form Element in Javascript and print its width, it will work I guess

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.